# Preferred way of adding new setting to all fields in a View?

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I'd like to add a new setting to all fields in Views. In other words, when you click on any given field in the "Fields" list, you get a popup with the selected field's configuration options. I would like to add a new settings element here.

If this was just about adding a new setting to a specific custom field handler, then I would just create a new field handler class and have it extend `views_handler_field`. Then, I'd make my setting available by first defining it in `option_definition()` followed by adding a new form element in `options_form()`. However, I'd like the new setting to appear for **all fields regardless of field handler**.

What I've done so far is to simply provide an implementation of `hook_form_views_ui_config_item_form_submit()` to add the new setting. I'm adding my custom form element here as well as my own submit handler. In the submit handler I make sure to save the setting in `$form_state['handler']->options` in my submit handler.

However, is that the right way to go about it? Is there another way which Views facilitates and which would let me do things a little more clean so that I do not have to "mess" with the options array in my own submit handler, but rather have Views to actually know about my added universal field setting?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the module [Views Label Tooltips](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_label_tooltip) based on my technique to achieve this, and here's a post explaining it: http://thereisamoduleforthat.com/content/recipe-extending-views-handlers-without-subclassing